# Bind data from label to SQL data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I want to bind data from label in `DataListControl` to SQL data source and view it as `GridView` in other page.

I don't know how to get data from label and put it in database ...

I tried to code this but what I need is the way to `GetData` from label and put in to the variable.

I have created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   // string Name = Label.Equals(Namelable) // What should I do here to Get data from Lable?! 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Order", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);

    }
}
```

Any Idea what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your label is an `asp:Label`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", YourLabel.Text);
```

If you are referring to pulling a label from a `DataList` you need to *find* the control first e.g.

```
var label = dataList.Items[i].FindControl("yourLabel") as Label;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", label.Text);
```

FYI - it's generally not a good idea to couple your data access layer with your view...

Comment: It's not a Label Standard Control actually.
It's a data bind in a **DataList** and I put it in a label.

Comment: Thank you for your Time and advice dude.
I'm building a scenario for Oder action, I need to Grab ** Product Number** From this _DataList_ and **User_ID** from the user who open this session maybe from login _txtName_ 

any advice?

Comment: How you pull the `User_ID` field is entirely down to how your authentication/login process is setup. Could you give more information? Generally if you use the built-in ASP.NET authentication mechanisms you should be able to get the login name from `Request.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: I did not use login control or Createuserwizard control.

I built my own cuz I need to switch login between admin and customer.

all I need to focus right now is how to Grab Product Number from DataList and put it in Order Table

Comment: @AmeenChaabani well without any sort of information on how your authentication is setup I can't give any help with that part. I have already posted code which will pull a label field from a `DataList`, you just need to apply it to your code.

Comment: you can see this : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568395/create-asp-login-form-with-dropdownlist-for-multi-database-users>

Comment: "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Answer (score 0):

I think you requirement is to find the label inside a datalist and then bind its value

so if assuem you doing in itemcommand

you find the control there

```
stirng str = ((label)e.item.findcontrol("lable1")).text.trim();
```

rest code goes here